# MySQL simple search query

Tags: mysql

I've got this query, I've written it the way I thought was correct, but it's returning thousands of results and not any of them seem to match (unless by coincidence).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.name 
FROM auctioneers a,auctioneersloc al, auctioneerscont ac 
WHERE a.email LIKE "%mike.barker@example.co.uk%" 
OR ac.email LIKE "%mike.barker@example.co.uk%" 
ORDER BY name
```

I hope you can see what I'm trying to do here, but I can't see what I've done wrong!
Thanks for any help offered. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're experiencing is known as a "Cartesian product" (every record from one table joined to every record from another).  It's what happens when you join tables without specifying any "ON" or (adequate) "WHERE" conditions.

Without knowing what the common fields link your three tables together, I'll use a.id and assume that a foriegn key field called "auctioneers_id" exists on the auctioneersloc and auctioneerscont tables.  But you'll want something that looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,a.name 
FROM auctioneers a
INNER JOIN auctioneersloc al ON al.auctioneers_id = a.id
INNER JOIN auctioneerscont ac ON ac.auctioneers_id = a.id
WHERE a.email LIKE "%mike.barker@example.co.uk%" 
OR ac.email LIKE "%mike.barker@example.co.uk%" 
ORDER BY name
```

Of course, if rows in your "auctioneers" table do not *require* matching rows in the "auctioneersloc" or "auctioneerscont" tables, then you should use a LEFT JOIN (instead of an INNER JOIN).

On more of a personal, stylistic note, I try to **always** explicitly specify my JOINs.  Simply listing all the tables in the FROM clause works, but it relies on your WHERE clause to specify your JOIN conditions.  This is potentially bad from an application development standpoint, where if something happens to your WHERE clause while building your query string you'll get a Cartesian product.  Always remembering to specify the JOIN keywords should save you from accidental CP's like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly. Unfortunately, as much as I love MySQL and would love to be great at it, I've read up on joins and understand them basically, but they still seem voodoo to me, as does much of MySQL like foreign keys, etc... :( Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You should define how you want to join the different tables that you are using

eg. by including into the where something like  a.id = al.auction_id (depending on your db structure)

easiest way to never forget this is by using the join command ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? I'm wondering because there is no join used already, for the auctioneers a,auctioneersloc al part? I've just appended the auctioneerscont ac part to the end. :S

Comment: @i-CONICA when you list multiple tables in your FROM clause, you are implicitly doing an INNER JOIN.